# Skip login screen in case user is already logged in

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using firebase to authenticate my user. I created some activities and have login screen which I want to show if user is not logged in already. I defined most of activities in manifest as default, and login screen activity as main. Am I doing it properly? Which of screens should be defined in manifest as main? Login screen or screen with most of informations (right main)?

Comment: defined the login screen as default and check if the user logged in already by Shared Preferences if it does then navigate him to the main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use a splash screen as main , its's normally used to display some kind of progress before the application setup completely

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
    // Start home activity
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
    } else {
    // No user is signed in
    // start login activity
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, loginActivity.class));
    }

    // close splash activity
    finish();
 }
}
```

and to know if the user is already logged in as  mentioned in the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) :

> The recommended way to get the current user is by calling the getCurrentUser method. If no user is signed in, getCurrentUser returns null

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

It should return null if a user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Define your main screen as the default. Make sure your query if the user is logged in before requesting data that may lead to failure due to the fact that the user is not logged in. The reason for this case is in most scenarios, users will log in and you don't want to be running two activities every time your app starts.